# how to use a paramiko.PKey() in the .connect() method?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I would like to connect to an ssh server using an OpenSSH key passed to paramiko's `.connect()` method.

The following code raises `paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.` on `.connect()` even though the key looks correct:

```
import paramiko
# the key below is shortened for readability, it is made of blocks ending with \\n - in other words
# the return-carriage in the original file was replaced with \\n
key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEpQIBA(...)b+iro=\\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\n"

# this is to dump the key for checking a command-line connection with that key
with open("key.priv", "w") as f:
    f.write(key.replace('\\n', '\n'))

key = paramiko.PKey(data=key)
params = {
            'hostname': '10.0.0.1',
            'port': 22,
            'username': 'root',
            'look_for_keys': False,
            'timeout': 5,
            'pkey' : key
}  
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()  # Initiate SSH client
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  # allow to add unknown ssh key
res = ssh.connect(**params)
```

Running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aa/testsshkey.py", line 19, in <module>
    res = ssh.connect(**params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 307, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 519, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to have `\\n` and well as `\n` in `key`, no changes (both are accepted by `paramiko.PKey()`).

The code above also dumps the key to a file to test a command-line ssh connection, which succeeds:

```
host1$ chmod 600 key.priv
host1$ ssh root@10.0.0.1 -i key.priv
root@host2 #
```

Is there a specific format for the key to be passed to `paramiko.PKey()`? Its [docs](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.__init__) claim that

```
Raises SSHException: 
if a key cannot be created from the data or msg given, or no key was passed in.
```

which does not happen in my case (<strike>therefore I assume that the format of the key is acceptable</strike> Edit: I checked with a random string and the "key" is still accepted, so no checks are made on the correctness of the key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution using help from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963391/how-do-use-paramiko-rsakey-from-private-key):

```
# note the single backslash in \n
key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAwK(...)J90XccMb+iro=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
keyfile = StringIO.StringIO(key)
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(keyfile)
```

`key` can now be passed to the parameters as per the code in the question