# Pass private-key as string/text instead of passing file path in Python PYSFTP

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, private-key, pysftp

I would like to pass my actual private-key value as argument instead of providing the file path.

I have used below code as of now:

```
import pysftp
import os

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
if str(host_keys).lower() =='none':
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
else:
    cnopts.hostkeys.load(hostkeys)
filename = os.path.basename(localpath)
print(filename)
remotepath = os.path.join(remotefolder, filename)
print(remotepath)
with pysftp.Connection(host=hostname, port=int(port), username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts,private_key=private_key_filepath) as sftp:
    sftp.put(localpath, remotepath=remotepath)
```

Please suggest some way to pass it as text.

Example:

```
private_key='abcdmyprivatekeytext'
```

In actual scenario I will be placing my private-key text in secure vault.

Answer (score 5):

The pysftp can accept [`RSAKey`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey) in the `private_key` argument of [`Connection` constructor](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection):

```
# Set your private key as a string
PRIVATE_KEY = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

# Use 'io.StringIO' to read your string as a file-like object.
privkey = io.StringIO(PRIVATE_KEY)

# Use paramiko to create your RSAKey
ki = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(privkey)

# Connect using your key with pysftp
conn = pysftp.Connection(host=HOST, username=USER, private_key=ki)
```

*(originally posted by @Hana, but the answer is deleted now)*

This use of `private_key` argument is not backed by documentation as of pysftp 0.2.9, but it works. Other key types (`DSSKey`, `ECDSAKey`, `Ed25519Key`) are not accepted.

---

If you need to use other keys types, use Paramiko directly:
[SSH/SCP through Paramiko with key in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43958696/850848)

The pysftp is just an abandoned wrapper around Paramiko.
Prefer using Paramiko directly: [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)