# Is there a way to pass Python sshtunnel a key rather than a file?

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I am using the following library locally to connect to a remote server which works perfectly:

https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/

But I need to host my Python function as a Google Cloud Function.  Unfortunately the library only appears to be able to accept a file, not a key directly as a string.  This is the config:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    SERVER_HOST,
    ssh_username=SSH_USERNAME,
    ssh_pkey="my_filename.pem",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5412)
)
```

If I try to insert something like this:

```
SSH_KEY = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""
```

Then amend the ssh_pkey line to:

```
ssh_pkey=SSH_KEY
```

My expectation would be that it would work but it looks to be like the library doesn't allow this.  I've looked at the source code here and it appears that it's [this](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py) is causing the issue.

```
@staticmethod
def get_keys(logger=None, host_pkey_directories=None, allow_agent=False):
    """
    Load public keys from any available SSH agent or local
    .ssh directory.
    Arguments:
        logger (Optional[logging.Logger])
        host_pkey_directories (Optional[list[str]]):
            List of local directories where host SSH pkeys in the format
            "id_*" are searched. For example, ['~/.ssh']
            .. versionadded:: 0.1.0
        allow_agent (Optional[boolean]):
            Whether or not load keys from agent
            Default: False
    Return:
        list
    """
    keys = SSHTunnelForwarder.get_agent_keys(logger=logger) \
        if allow_agent else []

    if host_pkey_directories is not None:
        paramiko_key_types = {'rsa': paramiko.RSAKey,
                              'dsa': paramiko.DSSKey,
                              'ecdsa': paramiko.ECDSAKey,
                              'ed25519': paramiko.Ed25519Key}
        for directory in host_pkey_directories or [DEFAULT_SSH_DIRECTORY]:
            for keytype in paramiko_key_types.keys():
                ssh_pkey_expanded = os.path.expanduser(
                    os.path.join(directory, 'id_{}'.format(keytype))
                )
                if os.path.isfile(ssh_pkey_expanded):
                    ssh_pkey = SSHTunnelForwarder.read_private_key_file(
                        pkey_file=ssh_pkey_expanded,
                        logger=logger,
                        key_type=paramiko_key_types[keytype]
                    )
                    if ssh_pkey:
                        keys.append(ssh_pkey)
    if logger:
        logger.info('{0} keys loaded from host directory'.format(
            len(keys))
        )

    return keys
```

I've never monkey patched anything before so looking at this, could I somehow override this manually?

Comment: Have you considered a `/dev/fd/NN` handle? You can have a subprocess holding the other end, ready to write your file's' contents.

Comment: ...that said, `get_keys` _does_ look quite self-contained enough to monkeypatch if you're so inclined.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you could create a [named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51239081/).  Although the answer does use Win32API to read the file (client), a straight forward call to `open(r"\\.\pipes\Foo")` seems to be enough on my system.

Comment: It’s not Windows. I already have it working on Ubuntu. The question is getting it to work with GCP Cloud functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I solved it, hope it helps someone. First I used Python to print out a base64 encoded key of my key file 'temp_key.pem':

```
import base64
with open('temp_key.pem', 'rb') as f:
    blob = base64.b64encode(f.read())

print(blob)
for_google_cloud_function = blob.decode('utf-8')
print(for_google_cloud_function)
```

The output of this I used an my environment variable SSH_KEY_BLOB.  In my GCP Cloud Function I then added this:

```
# decode key back into a useable form from base64
SSH_KEY_BLOB_DECODED = base64.b64decode(SSH_KEY_BLOB)
SSH_KEY = SSH_KEY_BLOB_DECODED.decode('utf-8')

# pass key to parmiko to get your pkey
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(io.StringIO(SSH_KEY))

# setup your SSHTunnel like normal
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    remote_server_ip,
    ssh_username=SSH_USERNAME,
    ssh_pkey=pkey,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
)
```

That way the key is not hard coded and the function is self sufficient from the file.  They may be better ways but this worked for me.

Comment: If you combine this with the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963391/how-do-use-paramiko-rsakey-from-private-key it becomes a little more elegant.

Comment: Which solution?  When I tried all other solutions I found at the time, whilst they would work locally, they didn't store well in a hosted environment variable.

Comment: For MAC, there is a bug in the paramiko library, so you have to use ssh.connect(ssh_host, username=ssh_username, pkey=mykey, disabled_algorithms={'pubkeys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']})